# Creating node with multiple custom blocks, best method

Tags: nodes, blocks, theming

What is the best method to create a node that includes multiple custom blocks with content related to only this node? The main concern is having a method that content editors will be able to understand with all the blocks related to this node editable from the node edit page for example. Having multiple custom blocks with each having an edit page is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the context module https://drupal.org/project/context. With context you can specify that certain blocks only appear on a path specified so if you only wanted them to appear on the page with the url applepoluza you could do so.

As for being able to edit the blocks from the node edit page, perhaps you could set a context with a path to the edit page of the specific node to display a new custom block and in that custom block put in a list of links to each of the desire custom block edit pages. That would a be a pretty simple way to be able to accessibly access all of the custom blocks edit pages from the node edit page.

To directly edit the blocks on a node edit page would get pretty messy but could probably be done with something like Entity Fields and a bit of hard coding if you REALLY wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) is something you could use here - Youre bascially creating a list of related content on the same page - you could also set it so that each piece of content could be editable from that page

[views](https://drupal.org/project/views):

> You need Views if
>
> - You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort    it differently.
> - You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to    sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
> - You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain    type.
> - You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display    articles the way you like.
> - You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of    some particular type.
> - You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
> - You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable    Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of
>     "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and
>     displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts
>     for that month.
>
> Views can do a lot more than that, but those are some of the obvious
>   uses of Views.